# wcf exception - Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message

Tags: wcf-security

I have a c# application that uses WCF.
when I'm trying to approach to a server method I'm getting an exception in the client side (when using diagnostics):

> Security processor was unable to find
>   a security header in the message. This
>   might be because the message is an
>   unsecured fault or because there is a
>   binding mismatch between the
>   communicating parties.   This can
>   occur if the service is configured for
>   security and the client is not using
>   security.

from some reason I get this ex. only when I'm using multiple clients. the clients succeed to connect to the server but some of them fail when calling the server method.

I've tried to add to the security configuration in my custom binding - includeTimestamp ="false" and it still did not work.

Thanx,
Amir